# "find and xargs" don't work as expected: How to get the basename of an arg from xargs?

Tags: xargs, command-substitution

I want to shrink some pdfs in a folder using a script and cron.

The main command is as follows:

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -i shrinkpdf.sh -out="./folder/file.pdf" in={}
```

I want the outfile to have the same name as the in-file, so i tried:

```
-out=`basename {}`
```

I don't understand the results. The command between the `` gets executed, but it returns the whole path, not only the basename.

Just playing around with different commands shows, that command substitution generally works.

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -i echo `basename {}`
```

(echoes the full path)

**How can i extract the basename from the arguments given by xargs?!**